# fastAPI : How to print all the excecuted actual queries in terminal in every request and response

Tags: python, sql, fastapi

How can I print all the excecuted actual queries in terminal in every request and response , in fastapi.
it will be helpfull if you can give me a sample code.

Im using raw queries like :

```
await db.database.execute('''INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname) 
                     VALUES (:firstname, :lastname)''',
                    {'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname})
```

so I need to print the actual query which is excecuted in db. (for ease of debug the query) how can I write a middleware for print the actual query after excecution.

Comment: Have you looked at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4683)? There's a solution there that might work for you. You might want to clarify your question as to whether you want the HTTP requests/responses, or if you want the SQL of database queries that occur as a result. Your question reads as unclear to me.

Comment: thanks for your patience, updated the question.please let me know if you need more clarification. thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't said anything about what `db.database` is - if it's SQLAlchemy, the provided answer should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLAlchemy, you can set echo True to display all queries by doing this:

```
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql://ajay:123_114@hostname/dbname",
    echo=True,
)
```

or this:

```
agent_db = SQLAlchemy(
    uri=os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI','mysql://ajay:123_114@hostname/dbname'),
    echo=True if os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_ECHO', 'False') == 'True' else False
)
```